# Bing maps binding to DataBase Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

I have a SilverLight application and i'm using Bing map sdk , anyway i followed the tutorial in this link :
[Bing Maps Bindings](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/433/posts/12005/bing-maps-binding-xml-data-source.aspx)

and he uses XML file as a data source , but in my situation i'm using a database , how can i reach the same result using a database connection.Thanks.

I made 'silverlight-enabled wcf service' and put a method like this:

```
 public  DataTable GetCustomer()
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectToDB"].ConnectionString;

    DataTable dataTable;
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select ID,Name,Lat,Long from Customers";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

but i don't know how to bind the result of this method and use it in this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LogoTemplate">
        <m:Pushpin m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding ????}" >
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ????}"></TextBlock>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </m:Pushpin>
    </DataTemplate>
    <t:LocationDataCollection x:Key="LocationList" IsDataSource="True"/>
```

i mean what should i put instead of '????' , or should i use a different return type from my wcf method..or what? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a RIA Serivce or WCF service or ASMX service to get the data from the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197940(v=vs.95).aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994616/how-to-connect-database-in-silverlight-applications
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/235874/how-to-connection-MS-access-database-in-silverligh

Thanks
Deepu

Comment: thank your for your answer and I've updated my question , i hope i make it clear now.